# Regular expression with two unique requirements

Tags: regex

I would like a regular expression that matches the following string:

```
"( one , two,three ,four, '')"
```

and extracts the following:

```
"one"
"two"
"three"
""
```

There could be any number of elements. The Regular expression:

```
"\[a-zA-Z\]+|(?<=')\\s*(?=')"
```

works, but the library I am using is not compatible with look-around assertions.

Do I have any options?

Comment: `\[` what is that ?

Comment: Try to split on punctuation and whitespace `[\s,.'()]+`

Answer (score 1):

This expression would likely capture what we might want to extract here:

```
(\s+)?([A-Za-z]+)(\s+)?|'(.+)?'
```

which we might not want other additional boundaries and our desired outputs are in these two groups:

```
([A-Za-z]+)
(.+)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TZSlMp/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Test

```js
const regex = /(\s+)?([A-Za-z]+)(\s+)?|'(.+)?'/gm;
const str = `"( one , two,three ,four, '')"`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Emma, it's almost what I need, however for the '', it needs to capture an empty string rather than the single quotes.